# Linq query that finds duplicates and removed them from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a LINQ query that will look for duplicates in 2 lists and remove them from the first list.

The code bellow will find the duplicate and return them, but I would like the query to return the unique items from notificationsFirst:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InnerJoinExample();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        class Notification
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public static void InnerJoinExample()
        {
            Notification first = new Notification { Name = "First", Id = 1 };
            Notification second = new Notification { Name = "Second", Id = 2 };
            Notification third = new Notification { Name = "Third", Id = 3 }; 
            Notification fourth = new Notification { Name = "Fourth", Id = 4 };
            Notification fifth = new Notification { Name = "Fifth", Id = 5 };

            List<Notification> notificationsFirst = new List<Notification> { first, second, third };
            List<Notification> notificationsSecond = new List<Notification> { third, fourth, fifth };

            var query = from notiFirst in notificationsFirst
                        join notiSecond in notificationsSecond on notiFirst.Id equals notiSecond.Id
                        select new Notification { Name = notiFirst.Name, Id = notiFirst.Id };


            foreach (var not in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\"{not.Name}\" with Id {not.Id}");
            }
        }

        // This code should produce the following:
        //
        // "First" with Id 1
        // "Second" with Id 2
    }
}
```

Comment: [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Except` method in combination with `Intersect`.

The idea is to find out the *intersection* list of the given initial lists using `Intersect` and then just `Except` that list from first *collection*.

```
var query = notificationsFirst.Except(notificationsFirst.Intersect(notificationsSecond));
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Works like a charm. In the real code, notificationSecond is actually a DBContext and I'm trying to do this against a database asynchronously.  `var query = notificationsFirst.Except(notificationsFirst.Intersect(await _context.Notifications));` But it's complaing that DbSet does not have GetAwaiter

Comment: @Q-bertsuit, you should use `await _context.Notifications.ToListAsync()`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch!