# Intersecting elements in Entity Framework entities with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity Framework entity in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project called `Tag`, which is a simple model:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagNameNormalized { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy {get; set; }
}
```

A user can add tags from the website, and these tags are stored in a `ICollection<Tag>`. But I want to store only new tags, and not duplicates.

At some point, I need to evaluate the `ICollection` that holds the newly added tags against the ones already stored in the database (`_context`). I just want unique names (the `TagName` property), the other properties can be the same.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
ICollection<Tag> duplicateTags = _context.Tags.ToList().Intersect(tagsToCheck).ToList();
```

but this is probably not doing what I want, because it will evaluate all of the model's properties.

What kind of Linq query should I use, where I evaluate just the `TagName` property, but still select the whole entity?

Any help and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Check this answer, it will help to filter out duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597757/10646316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `linq` <kbd>Join</kbd>

```
ICollection<Tag> duplicateTags = _context.Tags.Join(
                                  tagsToCheck,
                                  t => t.TagName, c => c.TagName, 
                                  (t,c) => t).ToList()
```

The above will give the duplicate tag objects.

Another way

```
var tagsNameToCheck = tagsToCheck.Select(t => t.TagName);
ICollection<Tag> duplicateTags = _context.Tags.Where(
                                  t => tagsNameToCheck.Contains(t.TagName))
                                  .ToList();
```

Point to notice that `_context.Tags.ToList()` would bring all `tags` from database into memory which can be a performance issue in your case if there are numerous tags. Would suggest to go for 2nd solution.

Answer (score 0):

Morgan,

You can use `Distinct()`. For example:

```
ICollection<Tag> duplicateTags = _context.Select(t => t.TagName).Distinct().ToList()
```

Does this answer your question?